# How to throw custom error message from API Gateway custom authorizer

Tags: aws-api-gateway

[Here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/python/api-gateway-authorizer-python.py#L30-L31) in the blue print says, API gateway will respond with 401: Unauthorized.

I wrote the same `raise Exception('Unauthorized')` in my lambda and was able to test it from Lambda Console. But in POSTMAN, I'm receiving status `500` 
with body:

```
{
  message: null`
}
```

I want to add custom error messages such as "Invalid signature", "TokenExpired", etc., Any documentation or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

This is totally possible but the docs are so bad and confusing.

Here's how you do it:

There is an object called `$context.authorizer` that you have access to in your gateway responses template. You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Here is an examample of populating this `authorizer` object from your authorizer lambda like so:

```js
// A simple TOKEN authorizer example to demonstrate how to use an authorization token 
// to allow or deny a request. In this example, the caller named 'user' is allowed to invoke 
// a request if the client-supplied token value is 'allow'. The caller is not allowed to invoke 
// the request if the token value is 'deny'. If the token value is 'Unauthorized', the function 
// returns the 'Unauthorized' error with an HTTP status code of 401. For any other token value, 
// the authorizer returns an 'Invalid token' error. 

exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    switch (token.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); 
    }
};

       var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
            var authResponse = {};
            
            authResponse.principalId = principalId;
            if (effect && resource) {
                var policyDocument = {};
                policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; 
                policyDocument.Statement = [];
                var statementOne = {};
                statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; 
                statementOne.Effect = effect;
                statementOne.Resource = resource;
                policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
                authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
            }
            
            // Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.
            authResponse.context = {
                "stringKey": "stringval custom anything can go here",
                "numberKey": 123,
                "booleanKey": true,
            };
            return authResponse;
        }
```

They key here is adding this part:

```
// Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.

        authResponse.context = {
            "stringKey": "stringval custom anything can go here",
            "numberKey": 123,
            "booleanKey": true,
        };
```

This will become available on $context.authorizer

I then set the body mapping template in gateway responses tab like this:

```
{"message":"$context.authorizer.stringKey"}
```

**NOTE**: it must be quoted!

finally - after sending a request in postman with `Authorization` token set to deny I now get back a payload from postman that looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "stringval custom anything can go here"
}
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that Gateway Responses are only applied after you re-deploy your API. You can also utilize `Response Headers` instead of editing the default `Body Mapping Template` to keep global 403 errors to return correct error message body.

Comment: Even if that works, looks pretty hacky. According to AWS docs, the purpose of that context object is:

"In addition to returning an IAM policy, the Lambda authorizer function must also return the caller's principal identifier. It can also optionally return a context object containing additional information that can be passed into the integration backend. For more information, see Output from an Amazon API Gateway Lambda Authorizer."

Source:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Comment: If I throw an error from inside the authorizer like `throw new Error("blabla")`, why the error message is not `{message: "blabla"}`? Without such behavior we can't send custom error messages with 500 status codes.

Comment: @walter_dl have you find any solution? I tried as mentioned by maxwell but it's not working for me

Comment: What's the advantage of returning a 401: "Unauthorized" (or any other denial message), versus generating a DENY IAM policy?

Comment: @Maxwell Thank you so much. It was of great help.

Comment: NOTE: This only seems to work for the 403 "Access Denied" gateway response. I still do not see a way to pass context to the 401 "Unauthorized" gateway response. That can only be triggered by `callback("Unauthorized")` which does not receive the authorizer context. This seems like a huge limitation by AWS.

Comment: @walter_dl, whichever language you choose, it would be best to just have a catch-all exception and return a 403 access denied alongside a deny IAM permission set. This means you can set `$context.authorizer.message`, and change the **Access Denied** Gateway Response, and be able to set custom error messages.

Answer (score 6):

I used @maxwell solution, using custom resource `ResponseTemplates`. For deny response see below:

```
{
  "success":false,
  "message":"Custom Deny Message"
}
```

You can check this out here: https://github.com/SeptiyanAndika/serverless-custom-authorizer

Comment: Thanks for the repo, this is really useful for anyone trying to figure this out using the serverless framework.

Answer (score 3):

Maxwell is mostly correct. I tried his implementation and noticed that his message should go from :

{"message":"$context.authorizer.stringKey"}

to

{"message":"$context.authorizer.context.stringKey"}

Comment: I confirm this, but only worked for another error that are not 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 3):

As noted by [Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921803/how-to-throw-custom-error-message-from-api-gateway-custom-authorizer#comment118190501_49806967) far as I can see, the answer to the specific question - which mentions 401 related errors - is **NO**.

You can produce a generic `401 Unauthorized` but you cannot alter the error message.

That is you can customise the `403 Forbidden` (DENY) messages but not the 401's.

Note that I've used the NodeJS Lambda custom authorizers but not the Python version referenced in the question.

Comment: I confirm this, using:
{"message":"$context.authorizer.context.stringKey"}
Does not works on 401, but works on 403

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is causing the 500 `message: null` response. Possibly misconfiguration of the Lambda function permissions.

To customize the Unauthorized error response, you'll set up a Gateway Response for the `UNAUTHORIZED` error type. You can configure response headers and payload here.

Comment: Since the original poster is raising a raw `Exception`, the lambda authorization function errors out, which means it returns a 500 error. In API Gateway, this triggers the `Authorizer Failure` Gateway response, which has a default template of `{"message":$context.error.messageString}`. The default value of this key since the lambda "crashed" is empty, hence the return being {"message":null}. The `$context.error.messageString`property was never set.

Answer (score 1):

With my testing what i observed is , You **cannot** customize message when you throw exception from the lambda,
You can have customized messages when you return DENY Policy message from the authorizer

Here is how i am returning custom message when i DENY from the Authorizer, it in the **detail** field of
**authResponse.context** returned from custom Authorizer

you can also update status code to 401 instead of 403 .

[image]

Answer (score -3):

This can be easily achieved by using the context.fail() function.

**Example:**

```
const customAuthorizer: Handler = (event, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {        
    authenticate(event)
        .then((res) => {
            // result should be as described in AWS docs
            callback(null, res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            context.fail("Unauthorized");
        });
}
```

This will return a `401` response with following body.

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

This can also be achieved by throwing an error:

```
throw new Error('Unauthorized');
```

Comment: This will allow you to deny a request, but there is no mention of a custom error response message, as request in the original question