# How do I return a custom message from an AWS Lambda Authorizer (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda-authorizer

In lambda authorizer, the http status code returned for access denied, token expired etc are 403. 
How do i return a message 'Token Expired' in case the Token Expires.

context.fail method is not supported.
Raise Exception only creates log in cloudwatch.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    .
    .
    .
    # verify the signature
    claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)
    if time.time() > claims['exp']:
        print('Token is expired')
        return generatePolicy(claims['sub'], 'Deny', event['methodArn'])
    else:
    if(claims['cognito:groups'][0].lower()=='admin'):
        return generatePolicy(claims['sub'], 'Allow', event['methodArn'])
    else:
        return generatePolicy(claims['sub'], 'Deny', event['methodArn'])
    return claims
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to throw custom error message from API Gateway custom authorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921803/how-to-throw-custom-error-message-from-api-gateway-custom-authorizer)